# Background processing in DASH

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, plotly-dash

I have a DASH app built which does some data processing to display the result. It needs input from the user as well.

The problem that I am facing is the processing is heavy and it takes time. So, I want to run the processing in the background while the user is providing input and once the user asks for result I can display that.

The user does not have to wait for the processing to complete to display the result.

I am not sure how can this be achieved in a DASH app. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that i understand your case. It sounds like the result (which is calculated in the background) depends in the inputs, but that you would like it to be calculated before the user has finished selecting the inputs? That seems like a paradox. Could you elaborate and/or give an example?

Comment: Apologies if it's confusing. The calculation depends on the input and it will only be calculated once the user has finished selecting the inputs.